# Magento M2E PRO extension - does not charge tax

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

Does anyone use m2epro module to sell product to ebay? It is charging different amount of grand total compare with magento order. Our store is in Aus, and selling on eBay - Aus.

For example,

1. Magento store - grand total is $90 (tax - $9)
2. ebay return - grand total is $81

I have no idea why m2epro is not charging tax and where to edit the setting.

Sorry about to my English..if it is really hard to understand..

Cheers, thanks for reading this, give me some idea will be appreciated.

For more details,

http://docs.m2epro.com/display/eBayMagentoV6/Orders#Orders-OrderTaxSettings

I have set ebay & magento under Order Tax Settings.

Comment: We found that it is due to the setting in Order Tax Settings was wrong.

Sell on ebay > config > account setting > orders > Order Tax Settings > choose ebay

Answer (score 0):

We had this same question.  M2E cannot use your Magento tax settings to charge the customer on eBay.  You have to set up your eBay tax table and set "Order Tax Settings" to eBay in M2E.

This is frustrating for us, because some of our products have tax in certain states and other products have tax in others.  Magento is very good at creating these "IF" tax rules, but eBay does not. There isn't an easy way to do this.